# PHP + SQL : Search for event in the same day, same month, no matter the year

Tags: php, mysql, date, search, days

I want to create a "on this day" little website.
I have a problem when I want to search events in my database that happen "on that day". Like displaying an event from 12/10/**2019**, or 12/10/**2014**, or 12/10/**2010**. Not only from the **current year.**

What I have for the moment, is a PHP function which does an SQL request. But it only shows the event of the day from the current year.

```
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM memories WHERE datecontent LIKE '$todayDate'");
```

What can I change to search the search the same day + same month, no matter which year?

Comment: What is the type of the column `datecontent` in the database?

Comment: MySQL has DATE() and MONTH() functions, so you'd have to split up $todayDate into date and month parts, and use those functions to query.

Comment: The type of the column datecontent is DATE. It can be changed if necessary !

Comment: See DATE_FORMAT(). Or, if indexing is required, store month and day separately from year

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I'm not sure how to use DATE() and MONTH() in the SQL query when I need to search a column with 2 variable. can you give me an exemple please ?

Comment: @Strawberry I think create 3 columns might be a solution. I'll try if I don't find an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to return memories always matching today's date, you can do this entirely in SQL without the need for PHP variables. Here is a sample schema.

```
CREATE TABLE memories (
 id INT,
 datecontent DATE
);

INSERT INTO memories (id, datecontent)
VALUES (1,'2000-12-10'),(2,'1990-03-22'),(3,'2008-12-24');
```

We can match events that occurred *on this day* with the following style of SQL statement.

```
SELECT * FROM memories
WHERE MONTH(datecontent) = MONTH(CURDATE())
AND DAY(datecontent) = DAY(CURDATE());
```

Doing so in PHP would look like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM memories WHERE MONTH(datecontent) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND DAY(datecontent) = DAY(CURDATE())");
```

Comment: This is awesome, I'll try as soon as possible. Thank you for your response !

Comment: This is working as wanted, thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines will probably do what you're after depending on the type of datecontent.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"
SELECT * 
  FROM memories 
 WHERE DAY(datecontent)=".date("d")." 
   AND MONTH(datecontent)=".date("m"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

In my "memories" table, the date is located in my "datecontent" column.
Will the search work without selecting the column ?

Comment: It should do. I normally tend to avoid using SELECT * but I don't know what columns you have other than datecontent. If it doesn't just list the columns you require in the SELECT part. It's better practice to do this because then if the table order changes the result order won't.